# PHP - Compute time render between two datetime

Tags: php, mysql

Hi can you please help me on my project, Im having problem in computing the render hours between two datetime. To be specific, my problem is computing the night differential of employee between 10:00pm to 6:00am

```
e.g1: If the employee time in is 2017-01-01 21:00 (9pm) and the time out is 2017-01-02 05:00 (5am) the output will be: 7hours. 

e.g.2: time in = 2017-01-01 17:00 (5pm) and time out = 2017-01-02 02:00 (2am) the output will be: 4 hours.

e.g.3: timein = 2017-01-01 02:00 (2am) and time out = 2017-01-01 10:00 (10am) the output will be: 4 hours.
```

the count will start if the logs passed through between 10pm - 6am

Please help thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You mention MySQL. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far this is my work

```
function computeNightDifferential($time_in, $time_out)
{
    $start = "2016-01-01 22:00:00"; // 10pm
    $end = "2016-01-02 06:00:00"; // 6am

    $time_in = "2016-01-01 23:00:00";
    $time_out = "2016-01-02 06:30:00";
    $night_diff = 0;
    if($time_out > $start AND $time_out <= $end AND $time_in <= $start){
        $night_diff = abs(strtotime($start) - strtotime($time_out)) / 3600;
    }else if($time_out <= $end AND $time_in > $start){
        $night_diff = abs(strtotime($time_in) - strtotime($time_out)) / 3600;
    }else if($time_out > $end AND $time_in > $start){
        $night_diff = abs(strtotime($time_in) - strtotime($end)) / 3600;
    }else if($time_out > $end AND $time_in <= $start){
        $night_diff = abs(strtotime($start) - strtotime($end)) / 3600;
    }
    echo $night_diff;
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Is this part of the question?  What's the logic behind the if statement?

Comment: yes, this is part of question. the only time that night diff will start counting if the log occurs between 10pm to 6am. for example the time_in = 5pm and time_out = 11pm. this means starting from 10am the night diff will start to compute. less than 10pm will be ignored. but 10pm upto nextday of 6am will do. so in our input. 10pm - 11pm are the range of time will count the night differential. so the output will be: 1hour.

Comment: Could you edit all of this information into your question? The logic you are using is a little unclear. Hpwever, the example is very helpful. Could you include another when you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43434677/edit)?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<?php
$output = abs((strtotime("2017-01-01 21:00") - strtotime("2017-01-02 05:00")) / 3600);
echo $output; // Outputs 8
```

Comment: the count will start only at 22:00 (10pm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unix time:

```
$Date1 = strtotime(date("2017-01-01 17:00"));
$Date2 = strtotime(date("2017-01-02 02:00"));
$hours = ($Date2 - $Date1) / 3600;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime functions for this:

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("2017-01-01 21:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2017-01-02 05:00");
if (($date1->format('H') >= 22) && (($date2->format('H') <= 6))) {
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%h hours');
} else {
    echo "0 hours";
}
```

This outputs:

```
+8 hours
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php